# Saving category from collection resets include_in_menu

Tags: magento-1.9, category, collection, default-values

Sometimes it is convenient to save a category directly from the collection it was loaded. For instance, for all categories of which the `name` attribute starts with `foo`, I want to update the `meta_title` attribute with the name followed by `bar` as follows:

```
/** @var Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Collection $categoryCollection */
$categoryCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection');
$categoryCollection->setDisableFlat(true);
$categoryCollection->addAttributeToFilter('name', ['like' => 'foo%']);
foreach ($categoryCollection as $category) {
    /** @var Mage_Catalog_Model_Category $category */
    $category->setData('meta_title', $category->getData('name') . ' bar');
    $category->save();
}
```

This does work, but as side-effect: the `include_in_menu` attribute is reset to 1.

What is the cause of this and how can this be circumvented?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that when saving an EAV entity, the `beforeSave` and `afterSave` methods of the backend models of **all** attributes are executed, even when they are not part of the collection: the method `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract::save` calls the methods `_beforeSave` and `_afterSave`, which call the method `walkAttributes` with `backend/beforeSave` or `backend/afterSave` as the first arguments.

The method `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Backend_Abstract::beforeSave`, which is used by most attributes, sets the default value of the attribute on the supplied object in the following circumstances:

1. The object does not have an entry in its internal `$data` array.
2. The default value of the attribute is non-empty.

The first condition applies to most attributes when loading via a collection. The second condition only applies to the `include_in_menu` attribute (in a standard Magento setup).

To work around this issue, simply add the `include_in_menu` attribute to the collection query:

```
$categoryCollection->addAttributeToSelect('include_in_menu');
```

Another issue that the `afterLoad` methods of the attribute backend models are not called (thanks to [Marius](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/146/marius) for the warning). On a default Magento installation, this causes issues with the following attributes:

- `created_at`: the value is *not* converted from UTC to the current store time zone on load. On save, the value *is* converted back to UTC (which it already was), leading to incorrect `created_at` dates.
- `available_sort_by` (if it is part of the collection and its value is not `NULL`): the comma-separated value is *not* replaced by an array. On save, the value is reset to `NULL`.

To resolve this, you can trigger the `afterLoad` methods by adding the following to the loop body:

```
$category->getResource()->loadAllAttributes($category)->walkAttributes('backend/afterLoad', array($category));
```

BTW This does not seem to harm performance that much: all category attributes are also loaded when saving the category, **and** Magento caches the attribute instances in the `Mage_Eav_Model_Config` singleton. So it seems that when loading and saving multiple categories, each attribute is only loaded once.

Similar to the issue that the `beforeLoad` method is not called for any attribute, the method `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract::_loadModelAttributes` is not called. This method does two things for every attribute:

1. Call `$object->setData($attributeCode, $attributeValue)` where `$attributeValue` is loaded from the database.
2. Call `$attribute->getBackend()->setEntityValueId($object, $valueId)` where `$valueId` is the primary key of the attribute value in the corresponding attribute table.

When loading EAV collections, the similarly named method `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract::_loadAttributes` is called, which does the former *but not the latter*. As a result, the corresponding `getEntityValueId` method always returns an empty value. This only causes issues when deleting attribute values from the backend table. For categories (and also products) this only happens when setting an the value of an attribute with global scope to `false`.

To avoid the issues with not being able to delete values of attributes with global scope, do not call `$object->setData($attributeCode, false)` for such an attribute. When it is necessary to clear an attribute, you can use `null` instead of `false`, which results in an `UPDATE` query on the attribute backend table instead of a `DELETE` query.

Answer (score 1):

You should never call `save` if you did not call `load` before on the same object.
Even if you add the attributes to the collection, the `beforeLoad` and `afterLoad` methods are not called and they could have an impact on the object state.

Adding

```
$categoryCollection->addAttributeToSelect('include_in_menu');
```

may solve your problem for this particular case, but it may damage something else.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Although I know that it is better to call load on an object before save, the problem in general is that when I need to update many categories at once, performance becomes a real issue. I have checked the methods you mentioned: beforeLoad does not exist, but afterLoad causes issues with the attributes created_at (the value is converted from current store time zone to UTC) and available_sort_by (replace comma-separated value by an array). This can be resolved by the calling afterLoad on the backend models of these attributes. I will include this as a warning to my answer.